# I have been downloading nodemon a npm package but it's not working and this my code

Tags: node.js

I have been downloading nodemon a npm package but it's not working
and this my code

```
    MacRonys-MacBook-Air:Weather-Project macrony$ npm i nodemon

> nodemon@2.0.9 postinstall /Users/macrony/Desktop/Weather-Project/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

npm WARN weather-project@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ nodemon@2.0.9
added 118 packages from 57 contributors and audited 168 packages in 5.437s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

MacRonys-MacBook-Air:Weather-Project macrony$ nodemon app.js
bash: nodemon: command not found
MacRonys-MacBook-Air:Weather-Project macrony$ nodemon app
.js
bash: nodemon: command not found
MacRonys-MacBook-Air:Weather-Project macrony$ nodemon app.js
bash: nodemon: command not found
```

please help meee

I would be very thank ful

Answer (score 1):

When you install a package as a local one (without the global `-g` option), you have 2 options to access that package:

1. Define a script in `package.json` that includes the package, such as `"start": "nodemon app.js"`, then run `npm start`.
2. While inside the project's folder, use `npx`: `npx nodemon app.js`.